# analysing my android app's ANR

Tags: java, android

Could someone pls. help me analysing the following ANR for my android app. I am new to the ANR world.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40ce24c0 self=0x185da18
| sysTid=2641 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1075160444
| schedstat=( 13982089096 731925534 8330 ) utm=1371 stm=27 core=0
at android.graphics.Paint.native_getTextRunAdvances(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1683)
at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1649)
at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:168)
at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:200)
at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:281)
at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:283)
at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:169)
at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6471)
at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6369)
at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6715)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12790)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1374)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:663)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12790)
at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1164)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:312)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12790)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12790)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12790)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:815)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12790)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2218)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12790)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1147)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:965)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Thread-275" prio=5 tid=19 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419c17e8 self=0x1bc3948
| sysTid=2679 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=28864560
| schedstat=( 14379768 4029537 49 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=1
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=18 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41846738 self=0x1a5ae10
| sysTid=2678 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=28757152
| schedstat=( 373307 159769 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41841e48> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=18 (AsyncTask #2)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Thread-271" prio=5 tid=17 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x419ae098 self=0x1b56b98
| sysTid=2674 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=28672672
| schedstat=( 21873077 12209999 79 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x419aaf98> (a com.google.ads.internal.c)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at com.google.ads.internal.c.run(SourceFile:756)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Thread-268" prio=5 tid=12 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4198b428 self=0x1b35a88
| sysTid=2671 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=28578968
| schedstat=( 24263467 36899769 115 ) utm=0 stm=2 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41986178> (a com.google.ads.internal.c)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at com.google.ads.internal.c.run(SourceFile:756)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4146c868 self=0x1ab9608
| sysTid=2665 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=28020336
| schedstat=( 5055464 9107460 14 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41828438> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=14 (AsyncTask #1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"CookieSyncManager" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41848f90 self=0x1a91248
| sysTid=2663 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=27888536
| schedstat=( 3302152 6325925 8 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:122)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.webkit.WebSyncManager.run(WebSyncManager.java:90)
at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.run(CookieSyncManager.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41888dc8 self=0x1a8e838
| sysTid=2661 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27846328
| schedstat=( 313471591 130332562 1238 ) utm=23 stm=8 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41987fe8> (a android.webkit.CallbackProxy)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:1001)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.handleUrl(BrowserFrame.java:654)
at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.nativeServiceFuncPtrQueue(Native Method)
at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:113)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:738)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41456440 self=0x1a28a50
| sysTid=2654 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27429392
| schedstat=( 1705920 9067694 8 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41455b48 self=0x1a27af0
| sysTid=2653 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27416912
| schedstat=( 1736770 15136000 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41452350 self=0x1a25040
| sysTid=2652 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27413984
| schedstat=( 7733459 8833156 18 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4143ad08 self=0x1a247d8
| sysTid=2651 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=26970456
| schedstat=( 239845 2467077 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:213)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4143abb0 self=0x1a24388
| sysTid=2650 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=26968904
| schedstat=( 1796155 2710308 9 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x40cd85d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4143aa48 self=0x1a23f38
| sysTid=2649 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=27400544
| schedstat=( 958695 2574075 22 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x40cd84f8> 
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:128)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:8...
```

Comment: looks like your blocking the ui thread. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just don't run long (or things that could on some cases be long) operations on the UI thread.

this includes: DB operations, internet operations, complex calculations, large storage operations (like writing a large file) , ...

each of those operations can run on asyncTask , a new thread, a service with a thread , an intentService, syncAdapter, thread pool ,...

when the operation are finished, you can use a Handler object to tell the UI everything has finished.

Comment: I have around 2000 lines of text which I am displaying on the textview wrapped by scrollview. Shall I split it into multiple screens with swipe/next,previous buttons or some better alternative is there?

Comment: yes, this is very probelmatic. there are however many possible solutions. i think the best one for you could be a listView with multiple textView instances. if you are new to listView, watch the google io lecture "the world of listView" : http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally an ANR occurs if an application cannot respond to user input. The most common case is when you do some heave tasks in the main UI thread. That tasks blocks the work flow and thus creats ANR.

To resolve this you should use different thread rather than the UI thread to perform the heavy tasks. You canuse different worker thread, AsyncTask or post Runnable to handler to perform the tasks.

To know details about ANR and resolving this check this [nice article](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

Answer (score 0):

`ANR` may caused due to:

1. Broadcast receiver timeout
2. keyDispatching timeout
3. Service timeout

first search the `'timeout'` keyword in yours log, then only I can help you